# timestampdiff not deleting row over 5 minutes old

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to delete messages 5 minutes after they have been send using `TIMESTAMPDIFF() > 300` but they are not getting deleted.
My code:

```
$sql3 = "DELETE FROM `chat` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIME(),`timeSend`) > 300";
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql3)) {
    echo "error :" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

This code runs every second using an ajax request.
And the error echo doesn't show so it is supposed to work.

Table:

```
|--id--|--name--|--message--|--timeSend--|
|--1---|-name1--|--Hello!---|--09:32:00--|
|--2---|-name2--|--Heeey!---|--09:32:05--|
|--3---|-name3--|----How----|--09:32:12--|
|--4---|-name4--|--Are you?-|--09:32:20--|
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

EDIT:
If i run `select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,timeSend, CURRENT_TIME()) from chat` in PHPMyAdmin it returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using this:

```
 DELETE FROM `chat` WHERE timeSend < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```